# WordPress child theme override a parent theme include

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a WordPress child theme and need to overwrite certain widget templates. I'm trying to use this method to override the parent theme call: [The Right Way to Override Theme Functions](http://www.venutip.com/content/right-way-override-theme-functions).

However, I currently get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare hickory_homepage_load_widget()
>   (previously declared in
>   C:\wamp\www\greenpeaceNewBlog\wp-content\themes\gp-blog\inc\widgets\homepage_widget.php:8)
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\greenpeaceNewBlog\wp-content\themes\hickory\inc\widgets\homepage_widget.php
>   on line 10

The parent theme functions.php calls the templates like this:

```
include("inc/widgets/homepage_widget.php");
```

The homepage_widget.php file contains this:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'hickory_homepage_load_widget' );

function hickory_homepage_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'hickory_homepage_widget' );
}
```

I have a child theme duplicate widget directory (stylesheet_directory/inc/widgets/..) and a child theme functions.php. In my child functions.php, I have written this:

```
// Remove the default Thematic blogtitle function
function remove_hickory_widgets() {
    remove_action('widgets_init', 'hickory_homepage_load_widget');
}

// Call 'remove_thematic_actions' (above) during WP initialization
add_action('init','remove_hickory_widgets');

include("inc/widgets/homepage_widget.php");
```

Please help :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_hickory_widgets' );

function remove_hickory_widgets() {
    remove_action('widgets_init', 'hickory_homepage_load_widget' );
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_widgets' );
}

function custom_widgets(){
    // your widget code here
}
```