# override in child theme a function that is included in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to override a function included in parent's theme functions.php.

The function I am trying to override lives in functions/widget-fblikebox.php

What I have in my parent's functions.php:

```
include("functions/widget-fblikebox.php");
```

functions/widget-fblikebox.php begins with this:

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'facebook_like_load_widgets');

function facebook_like_load_widgets()
{
    register_widget('Facebook_Like_Widget');
}

class Facebook_Like_Widget extends WP_Widget {
```

I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687503/wordpress-child-theme-override-a-parent-theme-include) and this is what I did:

I created functions.php in my child theme and I entered there this:

```
<?php
// Add Facebook Like box Widget
include("functions/widget-fblikebox.php");
?>
```

I created a file in my child theme folder functions/widget-fblikebox.php that beginnis with this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_facebook_like_load_widgets' );

function remove_facebook_like_load_widgets() {
    remove_action('widgets_init', 'facebook_like_load_widgets' );
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_facebook_like_load_widgets' );
}

function custom_facebook_like_load_widgets()
{
    register_widget('Facebook_Like_Widget');
}

class Facebook_Like_Widget extends WP_Widget {
```

but I get an error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook_Like_Widget in /home/electronhe/over9000/www/wp-content/themes/truepixel/functions/widget-fblikebox.php on line 125
```

I googled this extensively and also tried everything that came to my mind to resolve this. I tried renaming the class in my child theme, using include_once in my child theme functions.php, etc. but to no avail. I you could please shed some light on this that would be greatly, greatly appreciated. The reason I am messing with this in the first place is that I would like to change the localization of the Facebook like box that comes with my theme (from mythemeshop, TruePixel) but it seems that there are no settings for the locale in the DB and the only idea of changing this that came to my mind was to redefine the class and hardcode proper locale in the URL of the iframe talking to FB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can't override function declarations. Once it is declared, that's it.

To get around this, you can ask the parent theme author to support function overriding (they would wrap their function declaration in an if statement that checks to see if the function has already been declared) or you can just modify their file manually (but be careful of updating the parent theme.